# Sertraline (Zoloft) safety?

Tags: medications, mental-health, overdose, side-effects

Sertraline, is a very commonly prescribed medication for patients suffering with mental health conditions such as Depression. Overdose guidelines, however, are not firmly presented.

What dosage of Sertraline, in the same period, would be classed as fatal? Additionally, what dosages are considered to cause serious bodily harm and visa versa?

For example, if the individual was a 60 kg, male.

Answer (score 3):

The overdose range of sertraline varies between individual to individual. For instance, in Reference 1, it is reported that an ingestion 13,500 mg did not result in a fatality. Another individual was not so fortunate. He died after taking 2,500 mg.

Long term effects do not appear to be common with SSRI overdosage (let alone sertraline). It would stand to reason that papers concerning sertraline overdosage would note any untoward long-term effects due to overdosage (References 2 and 3). However, Reference 4 does mention that "The incidence of seizures was 1.9% and coma was 2.4%" with SSRI medication.

**References**

1. OVERDOSE, HUMAN EXPERIENCE, http://www.rxlist.com/zoloft-drug/overdosage-contraindications.htm (Unsure of this source. Could not find references)
2. Suicidality and Suicide Attempt in a Young Female on Long-Term Sertraline Treatment, http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3662142/
3. Sertraline overdose, http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8808373
4. Relative toxicity of selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors (SSRIs) in overdose, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15362595